# Read GPS trace on apache server

Tags: php, apache, gps

Good morning community, a while ago I acquired a vehicle that has a tracking device installed (here it is known as GPS), the idea is to know where to locate it in case of theft (or something like that), the point is that the provider it does not exist (and consequently the web page with the trace interface are no longer available).

Then I decided to hire a plan in OVH and have the trace sent by the GPS saved in a database (mysql) to be able to show it with PHP code.

I already have the commands to configure the sending of the trace to an IP address and a specific port. The point is that I have no idea how to do so that the trace sent by the GPS is read on the Apache server. This is where I need your help.

Understand by "trace" to the information given by the GPS, here an example:

```
Lat:-6.74192
Long:-79.69947
Speed:0.00
Direction:31.79
Date:2018-06-15
Time:15:00:25
State:10000
```

I would appreciate any comment that helps. Thank you very much and greetings.

Comment: I can't help you much with the problem, but you know there are devices you can buy in China for next to nothing doing exactly what you describe? All they need is a simcard.

Comment: We are missing a lot of information.  What language and libraries do you have available on the GPS?  You could build a GET or POST request that is sent to the Apache server.  The server would then "deconstruct" the request and save it to database.  But if you already have a way to send to IP and port, you could write a program that listens to that IP and port, get the message and send the data to DB.  No need for Apache here.  But this is a very broad question, it could go in so many directions.